# How to update files with an isolation level like DBMS?

Tags: .net, database, powershell

Scenario: I have a file in the system that users will **replace** it at any time, and I need to record every change they make.

Solution: I'm using IO.FileSystemWatcher to record the changes, once users upload the new file, it will rename the old file with time-stamp and domain user's name to make it unique.

My problem is: If someone replace too fast, the program can't respond and it will miss to rename some items before the next replace.

My idea is: With a lock-based concurrency control DBMS, transactions can run with commit. What if I can do the same in the file system? Can we lock the file when running the program, and release it after "commit"? If can, how can I do it?

I'm implementing it using powershell, based on the .NET Framework:

```
Register-ObjectEvent $FileWatcher "Changed" -Action {
Add-content "C:\Projects\user_watching\log.txt" -value $(Get-Date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss)
Copy-Item "C:\Projects\user_watching\UserProfile.xml" "C:\Projects\housekeep\"$DomainUser"UserProfile"$(Get-Date -format yyyyMMddHHmmss)".xml"
}
```

Reference link about FileSystemWatcher Class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: NTFS and FAT are not designed to be transactional, although Longhorn did make an abortive attempt at that ten years back. So trying to implement ACID on top of something that very definitely is not ACID-capable on its own will almost certainly be extremely non-trivial.

Comment: I just found this relevant cmdlet, I may use Copy-Item as part of my transcation, but I can't work it on the replacement coz it's not part of my program. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847861.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are trying to implement is a mutex.  If you are trying to sync up multiple sessions and avoid race conditions, then this would be the way to go

Here is a link to get you started:
Ensuring that two PowerShell scripts don't run at the same time
http://www.lukepuplett.com/2013/01/ensuring-that-two-powershell-scripts.html?m=1